# Initializing an Elasticsearch DB via file

Tags: testing, docker, elasticsearch

I have an instance of elasticsearch running inside a Docker-container.

For testing purposes I would like to initialize the db with a set of data. Similar to postgres where one could write .sql files which where executed on container startup. What is the best way to accomplish this with elasticsearch?

Comment: You can map the elasticsearch data folder as a volume inside your Docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) to initialize Elasticsearch with test data.

The gist of it is, you create a [Newline delimited JSON](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec) file, as required by the Bulk API, like this:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

(Note the newline at the end of the file. It won't work without it.)

Then upload it to the bulk endpoint, which can be done with curl, like so:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary '@test-data.json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' 'localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty'
```